# MySQL workbench can't deal with MariaDB's new Invisible columns

Tags: mariadb, mysql-workbench

Recently upgraded to MariaDB 10.3 which has a new feature whereby we can create an invisible column like so:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD COLUMN `TestA` INT INVISIBLE;
```

But once I create this column, MySql Workbench will error on this table. Is there any way to workaround this? Or is there another GUI tool that can deal with this new column type?

Comment: [List on their kb](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/graphical-and-enhanced-clients/) no idea which ones keep up with later features sorry.

Comment: Yes, and there is also a link to a list of tools that support MariaDB enhanced features (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/applications-supporting-mariadb/).
I've tried mysql maestro, and at least it doesn't error, but it also doesn't see its Invisible attribute.

Comment: "error on this table" -- Please explain and show the message.

Comment: When I use the table structure tool on a table which contains an Invisible column, MysqlWorkbench generates the following message:

`Error Parsing DDL for tablename`

Then there is an option to view the DDL, which shows the full table CREATE statement with a red X marking the statement defining the Invisible colum

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Workbench currently supports MySQL version 5.6, 5.7 and 8.0 and has support for MySQL invisible <strike>columns</strike> indexes, (recursive) CTEs, JSON and all other (for a GUI relevant) features added to MySQL (like cached sha2 passwords).

Comment: *MySQL* invisible columns? I've heard of MariaDB invisible columns, but MySQL?

Comment: Oh, my fault, I confused columns with indexes.

Comment: As of MySQL 8.0.23, invisible columns are a feature. They work fine from MySQL Workbench too.